# Does space matter between @Secured and () with parameters

Tags: java

This question may sound very naive...Does the space between @Secured and () matters as shown below? Will this work?

```
@Secured (Roles.TARIFF_CALCULATION_RESULT_READ)

@Secured(Roles.TARIFF_CALCULATION_RESULT_READ)
```

Will both the above expressions work ?

Comment: What does the compiler tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I think it works. It is not sensitive to whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `Java`, both statement should work. This is unlike `Python` where indentation or code formatting makes a difference to your code.

**Example:**

```
int x = 10;
```

and

```
int    x    =  10;
```

works the same way in Java.